# By using styled components, how can I add some opacity to a background color that comes from an external prop?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

This is my code, below it you will find the question

```
import { printIntrospectionSchema } from 'graphql';
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Context } from '../../../Context/Context';
// DATA
function DurationIntervalSelection() {
  const tabsData = [
    {
      text: 'Duration',
    },
    {
      text: 'Interval',
    },
  ];
  // STATE
  const [selectedIndex, setselectedIndex] = useState(0);
  const { selected } = useContext(Context);
  console.log(selected.color, 'selected color');
  // FUNCTION
  const handleIndexSelection = (index) => {
    setselectedIndex(index);
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <TabsContainer backgroundColor={selected.backgroundColor}>
        <Indicator
          backgroundColor={selected.color}
          style={{
            left: `${selectedIndex * 50}%`,
          }}
        />
        {tabsData.map((tab, index) => {
          return (
            <Tab
              style={{
                color: selectedIndex === index ? 'white' : 'black',
              }}
              onClick={() => handleIndexSelection(index)}
              key={tab.text}
            >
              <p style={{ zIndex: 100 }}>{tab.text}</p>
            </Tab>
          );
        })}
      </TabsContainer>
    </Container>
  );
}
const Container = styled.div`
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0;
`;

const Indicator = styled.div`
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: -1; */
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: ${(props) => props.backgroundColor};
`;
const TabsContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: ${(props) => props.backgroundColor};
`;
const Tab = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
`;
export default DurationIntervalSelection;
```

As you can see from the above code i pass backgroundColor as a prop that takes some color from a React state.

```
<TabsContainer backgroundColor={selected.backgroundColor}>
```

And in the styled component I do:

background-color: ${(props) => props.backgroundColor};

But my question is, since i need to follow a design made by a colleague, how do i add opacity to the above background color without affecting the opacity of the whole div: TabsContainer. I mean, if i add on the TabsContainer -> opacity: 0.3 - for instance the whole TabsContainer div will be affected by the opacity, including the Tab div, while what I want is just to change opacity on the color itself so i do not affect any child. I hope it makes sense. Is there a way?

Answer (score 4):

Okay if your hex value comes from your backend, you can either create your own javascript function that converts hex to rgba or you can use a library like [polished](https://polished.js.org/docs/#rgba). They have a function named rgba that converts a hex string and adds an alpha value to it

```js
import { rgba } from 'polished'

const div = styled.div`
  background: ${(props) => rgba(props.backgroundColor, 0.3)};
`
```

Or you can apply it directly to the prop

```js
<TabsContainer backgroundColor={rgba(selected.backgroundColor, 0.3)}>
```

[Example CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-satoshi-5l0x3?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: The problem is that the data from the backend is coming in Hex rgb like: #00000, for instance. So when I do background-color: ${(props) => props.backgroundColor}; i do not know how add the opacity directly to the background color. that is the question:) - i tried to add on the TabsContainer (styled component div) an opacity but since it is a parent DIV is going to influence also the child DIV and I do not want that. I want to have opacity on the color itself which is the background of the parent DIV and not the background of the children too. Does it make more sense?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i did try your solution and if i add manually a color (without using the prop from the backend) it works but as soon as i add -     <TabsContainer backgroundColor={rgba(selected.backgroundColor, 0.3)}> nothing works, even though by console.logging selected.backGround color i still get a hex value. It seems so strange

Comment: by console logging how does the hex value look like? Are you sure it's a valid hex value that comes back from your backend?

Answer (score 0):

Since the data from the backend where right but I could not find a solution I have realised that I could have added to

```
<TabsContainer backgroundColor="rgba(255,255,255, 0.5)">
```

A background color on the white notes with opacity so to emphasise the color behind it in a lighter way